# store images into sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ios, database, image, sqlite

Below is my code to store images in the sqlite database. When I used it to store values it works and now I'm trying to store images in sqlite database. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I already searched and I can't get the answer what I need. Anyone help me with his code.

```
 sqlite3 *database;
    dbName=@"dataTable.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentpath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentdir=[documentpath objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPath=[documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;
   if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Name:%@,Company:%@,URL:%@",model.personName,model.companyName,model.imgurl);
        const char *insertSQL="insert into Persons(PersonName,CompanyName,ImgUrl,PersonImage)values(?,?,?,?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,insertSQL, -1, &compiledStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,1,[model.personName UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,2,[model.companyName UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,3,[model.imgurl UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
        sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStmt, 4, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], NULL);
        NSLog(@"Prepare");
        sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);

    }sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
**Thanks to everyone.. I cleared this issue by asked another question from here.. [store and retrieve image into sqlite database for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8728834/1083859) This may help to others.**

Comment: i m having code to read database in my appdelegate to view while app launched in my project....

Comment: Please ask only *one* question at a time.

Comment: @Sathya okk...can you help me with my 1st question..i will edit it..

Comment: You check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105570/saving-and-viewing-image-in-ios-app) link
for insert image into sqlite db in ios.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105570/saving-and-viewing-image-in-ios-app)
link to insert image into sqlite db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similair question with this answer: It's better if you use CoreData instead. It will be much easier for you to work with CoreDate instead of SQL. CoreData is pretty much an SQL database in a nice wrapper.

If you use iOS 5 you could easily add images to the database without having to worry about them being BLOBS (Binary Large Object) by checking "Allows External Storage".

Comment: I already know that..I have to develop app for ios4..i have to use sqlite3..i m going to use only 2 pictures...so i need to check out the correct code..anyway thank you..

Answer (score 2):

```
  const char *insertSQL="insert into Persons(PersonName,CompanyName,ImgUrl,PersonImage)values(?,?)"
```

You have 4 values to insert into your table & only 2 placeholders for the parameters. Correct them.

*Heck I ain't an iOS developer*

Comment: "not working only" is a bad comment. We aren't mind readers here to figure out what's going on your screen. Add some error logs, do *basic* debugging at least by yourself. @DineshRaja.MaG

Comment: Its a coding about SQLite database in iphone..I will not show any errors or bugs..simply we will not get the result for it..I put NSLog to print coding is working well..I found out It is not executing inside the sqlite_prepare_v2 statement...

Answer (score 1):

you just ADD libSqlite3.dylib to Linked FrameWork and Lilbraries and declared database varibles in .h file

```
  //Database Variables
  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *databasePath;
  @property (nonatomic)sqlite3 *contactDB;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backbtn;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *forwardbtn;
```

drag and drop UIImageView and name to that... i declared as imgView.
Goto .m file you just copy and paste that code

```
int i=1;
long long temp=0;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 

NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

 // Build the path to the database file
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"images.db"]];
//docsDir   NSPathStore2 *  @"/Users/gayathiridevi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/B5D4D2AF-C613-45F1-B414-829F38344C2A/Documents"  0x0895e160
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMAGETB (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,URL TEXT, CHECKSUM TEXT,IMAGE BLOB)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog( @"User table Not Created Error: %s", errMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog( @"User table Created: ");
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }

    else {

        NSLog( @"DB Not Created");
    }
}
[self saveImage];
[self showImage];   
}
 - (void)saveImage
  {  

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *insertSQL=@"INSERT INTO IMAGETB(URL,image) VALUES(?,?)";

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, [insertSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //NSString *url =@"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-vJBBGUtpXxk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADQ/nfgVPX1n-Q8/photo.jpg";
       //NSString *url =@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Junonia_lemonias_DSF_upper_by_Kadavoor.JPG";
       // NSString *url =@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Tibia_insulaechorab.jpg";


         NSString *url =@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/PNG_transparency_demonstration_2.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_2.png";
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
        NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
          sqlite3_bind_text(statement,1, [url UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 2, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

         NSLog(@"Length from internet : %lu", (unsigned long)[imageData length]);

    }


    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog( @"Insert into row id %lld",(sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(_contactDB)));
        temp =(sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(_contactDB));
    }
    else {

        NSLog( @"Error IN INSERT" );
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
}   
}

 - (void)showImage
 {

 sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
  const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
  if(sqlite3_open(dbpath,&_contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)

{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select IMAGE FROM IMAGETB WHERE ID = %d",i];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB,[insertSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0);
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0) length:length];

            NSLog(@"Length from db : %lu", (unsigned long)[imageData length]);

            if(imageData == nil)
                NSLog(@"No image found.");
            else
                _imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            NSLog(@"image found.");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
}




 -(IBAction)backBtn:(id)sender {

  if (i<=1) {}
  else{
    i=i-1;
    [self showImage];
   }  
 }
 -(IBAction)forwardBtn:(id)sender {
if(i==temp){}
else{

    i=i+1;
    [self showImage];        
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return values of bind_text and bind_blob and the step-call, print an error message when they fail.

Comment: bro...my code is not executing after sqlite_prepare_v2 statement..i dont know y?...anything i m doing wrong in that?

Comment: Make the else-part of the `if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,...` like `else NSLog(@"prepare failed (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));`. That show you more information.