# Saving and Viewing Image in ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ipad, sqlite

I just start develop an ios app just like Contact. 
It include Name, Birthday, Group(School, Work), BloodType, Image.. etc.

In that, other Data can insert by typing.
But, image can come from taking photo, download from facebook.. etc.

Input images into xcode is impossible. Bcoz, another images can come again and again.

How should i do? Please, advice me.

Comment: It's unlikely that app store wil approve your iOS app if it's just like Contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding taking photos or grabbing from your library, see [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) and the [Camera Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010400). For grabbing photos from Facebook, you should refer to its [API](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/), as that's a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: Thanks for all of your advices. I will try it. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1):

you just ADD libSqlite3.dylib to Linked FrameWork and Lilbraries and declared database varibles in .h file

```
   //Database Variables
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *databasePath;
   @property (nonatomic)sqlite3 *contactDB;
```

drag and drop UIImageView and name to that... i declared as imgView.

Goto .m file you just copy and paste that code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

// Build the path to the database file
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"images.db"]];
//docsDir   NSPathStore2 *  @"/Users/gayathiridevi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/B5D4D2AF-C613-45F1-B414-829F38344C2A/Documents"  0x0895e160
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMAGETB (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,URL TEXT UNIQUE, IMAGE BLOB)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog( @"User table Not Created Error: %s", errMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog( @"User table Created: ");
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }

    else {

        NSLog( @"DB Not Created");
    }
 }
 [self saveImage];
 [self showImage];   
 }

- (void)saveImage
{

sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *insertSQL=@"INSERT INTO IMAGETB(image) VALUES(?)";

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, [insertSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
    {

        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-vJBBGUtpXxk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADQ/nfgVPX1n-Q8/photo.jpg"]]];
        NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        //sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [@"" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        NSLog(@"Length : %lu", (unsigned long)[imageData length]);

    }


    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog( @"Insert into row id %lld",(sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(_contactDB)));
    }
    else {

        NSLog( @"Error IN INSERT" );
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
  }  
 }

- (void)showImage
{

sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
int i = 1;
if(sqlite3_open(dbpath,&_contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)

{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select IMAGE FROM IMAGETB WHERE ID = %d",i];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB,[insertSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0);
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0) length:length];

            NSLog(@"Length : %lu", (unsigned long)[imageData length]);

            if(imageData == nil)
                NSLog(@"No image found.");
            else
                _imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            NSLog(@"image found.");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
}
```

Its my code. You fix back and Forward Button to get details by changing that i value in 
     -(void)showImage 
function

Comment: See [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726075/store-images-into-sqlite-database) link for change photo by changing i value in Showimage() function.